# Static Constructor and Extension methods

Tags: c#, static, constructor

Wondering if my static constructor fails and throws exception if the extension methods would still work?  The logger is intended to help detect issues in the extension methods.  If they won't still work I will have to try catch and make sure the constructor succeeds.  I would prefer to be able to have it throw exception as hopefully calling code can log the error.   (This is just example code similar to what I'm thinking about)

```
     public static class Extensions 
     {

        private static readonly log4net.ILog log;
        private const TIME_TO_CHECK;

        static Extensions() 
        {
            log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger           (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);  //could maybe throw exception

            TIME_TO_CHECK = readInFromFile();  //could maybe           throw                           exception            }           

        public static DateTime StartOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startOfWeek) {
        int diff = dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek;
        if (diff < 0) {
        diff += 7;
      }
      return dt.AddDays(-1 * diff).Date;
    }
  }
```

I did search around (Hopefully this isn't a repeat) and found that throwing exceptions from static constructor is not generally good.  In most cases I think the classes were ones that could be instantiated and weren't just all extension methods.

Comment: If a static constructor throws an exception, the runtime will not invoke it a second time, and the type will remain uninitialized for the lifetime of the application domain in which your program is running. Most commonly, a TypeInitializationException exception is thrown when a static constructor is unable to instantiate a type or for an unhandled exception occurring within a static constructor. [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Wondering if my static constructor fails and throws exception if the extension methods would still work?

No. If a type initializer of any kind (whether using a static constructor or not) fails, the type is basically unusable thereafter.

It's very easy to demonstrate this...

```
using System;

static class Extensions
{
    static Extensions()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Throwing exception");
        throw new Exception("Bang");
    }

    public static void Woot(this int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Woot!");
    }
}

class Test
{

    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                i.Woot();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught exception: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Throwing exception
Caught exception: The type initializer for 'Extensions' threw an exception.
Caught exception: The type initializer for 'Extensions' threw an exception.
Caught exception: The type initializer for 'Extensions' threw an exception.
Caught exception: The type initializer for 'Extensions' threw an exception.
Caught exception: The type initializer for 'Extensions' threw an exception.
```

Comment: Thank you trying it would have been smart.  Hopefully it helps someone else.